# how can i add a swing application as a whole in a java applet?

Tags: applet

i have made a urdu editor using swing in java and now wana add it in an applet to make a gadget that will be be available online,

i am also reading the information of fonts from windows font folder is it possible to make an applet of it?

Comment: how to create applets: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've built a Swing application and its GUI main class is a JFrame, you basically just have to move the code from the JFrame to a JApplet.

There are lots of details about how an applet is different from an app, but you'll come across those and have to handle them somehow. You can always post more questions if you have specific problems.

There are two problems with reading fonts from the Windows font folder. One is that unsigned applets aren't allowed to access the user's file system. You can find some more information on applet signing here: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html

The second problem is that you don't know your applet will be running in a Windows environment. Even if so, you don't know the font folder will be where you think it is. You may be better off just using the fonts known to Java. Here's some information on where to find them: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/font.html#AVAILABLEJ.